# When creating multiple new lines, Sublime only leaves indented the final the line I end up on, and not those above it

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text, code, syntax, indentation

In Sublime, when you hit return, it auto-indents the new line, according to syntax. However, if I hit return more than once, going multiple lines down, the previous lines do not remain indented. They have no indentation at all, and if I wish to go back to them to add something, I have to manually indent them.

Sometimes I like to have some white space in my code for aesthetic reasons. Is there a solution to this? Some other editors leave the lines indented in this use case.

Comment: I have a hunch this is by design, as to not waste space with "unused" indents in source code. Then again, it could be a bug..

Comment: I figured it out. It's the setting "trim_automatic_white_space". Enabled by default, and setting it to false creates the behavior I want. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Setting "trim_automatic_white_space" to false (true by default) creates the behavior I want. Nice to know there was so much thought put into this editor as to include that option.

Comment: This has been bugging me for quite some time as well. Not badly... Just one of these little voices in the back of your head. (But I have lots of voices in my head so that's ok... :/ ) Your question inspired me to actually go and take a look at the sublime options. I found the same setting, was just going to post an answer when I saw that you answered your own. But MAN are there a lot of cool settings to play with \o/ Sublime FTW.

Comment: I will accept it but it says I can't accept my own answer until two days have passed—probably because this is a new account. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Default:  `"trim_automatic_white_space": true,`

> Trims white space added by `auto_indent` when moving the caret off the line.